# Unused Argument Error in function during a do.call loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, do.call

```
funMergeA <- function(x,y = NULL) {
    if (is.null(y)) {
        return(x)
    } else {
        return(funMerge(x,y,"a"))
    }
}

funMerge <- function(x,y,myby="a") {
    return(merge.data.frame(x,y,by=myby,all=TRUE))
}

b <- list(data.frame(a=1:10,b=rnorm(10)),
          data.frame(a=1:10,b=rnorm(10)),
          data.frame(a=1:10,b=rnorm(10)))
```

this works :

```
funMergeA(funMergeA(funMergeA(b[[1]],NULL),b[[2]]),b[[3]])
```

this doesn't :

```
do.call(funMergeA,b)
```

I am confused as to why the second one doesn't work. My understanding is that the 2 expressions are strictly equivalent. Is my understanding flawed ?

All help welcome !

Comment: `do.call(funMergeA,b)` is the same as `funMergeA(b[[1]], b[[2]], b[[3]])`, so your understand is flawed.

Comment: You need `Reduce(funMergeA,b)` - do.call works through b one at a time but is not recursive in the way that you need it to be.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Gustar for the helpful tip. If you want to post an answer i'll validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do.call` iterates through `b` one element at a time but is not recursive in the way that you need it to be.  You need `Reduce(funMergeA, b)`.